# cookie is not sent from browser (localhost) when check logs in koa server

Tags: node.js, cookies, axios, koa

I use Koa for api server, React in frontend, and use Axios for xhr.

when client request to api server in server-side-rendering, which means in node.js, I can see all headers coming from node.js. when I test with PostMan, I see all the headers included in request also.
However, when client get into CSR and do axios request, I couldn't see any headers from logs in api server except

```
{
  accept: 'application/json',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'axios/0.19.2',
  host: 'localhost:5001',
  connection: 'close'
}
```

I could find cookies are included in request headers when check chrome inspector - network tab,
but couldn't find why my localhost browser can't send headers with cookies appropriate.

for those who want to know how I setup both frontend and backend specifically,

Koa

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: verifyOrigin, // http://localhost:5000
  credentials: true,
}));

...

cookies.set("someCookieKey", someCookieValue, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    });
```

in React

```
const http = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
})

http.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

After stumble upon on this for a while, I found I send request to server with out request object.

If api server deal with some business logic with cookies or header something,
you better check client side omitted cookie or not.

Answer (score -1):

Probably `httpOnly: true` is a problem in this case. That parameter blocks read cookie by js in browser. Try set value to `false`.

Comment: the problem is not client can't read cookie in browser, but api server can't receive any cookies in headers. Actually httpOnly flag has nothing to do with server reading cookies from headers. It used for prevent XSS. Furthermore , if you don't use httpOnly: true, api server from different domain can't set cookie in browser

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand well.